# Not all code paths return a value for boolean method in class

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I'm very new at programming, and am trying to create a password management program using Windows Form Application in Visual Studio. Basically one can add, edit and save accounts in this.

I added an Account class, and in it I used a addAccount method. But it gave me an error that said not all code paths return a value. Why is this so? Please go slow with me; I am very new at this.

```
namespace thePass
{
    class Account
    {
        int numAccount;
        string[] AccountName;
        string[] Email;
        string[] Username;
        string[] Password;

        //constructors      
        public Account(string in_AccountName, string in_Email, string in_Username, string in_Password)
        {
            numAccount = 0;
            AccountName = new string[] { in_AccountName };
            Email = new string[] { in_Email };
            Username = new string[] { in_Username };
            Password = new string[] { in_Password };
                //NOT DONE KEEP GOING HERE CHECK NOTES FOR HELP maybe i leave as default?
        }

        public bool addAccount(string in_Account, string in_Email, string in_Username, string in_Password)
        {
            bool isFound = false;
            bool isAdded = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < numAccount; i++)
            {
                if (AccountName[i].CompareTo(in_Account) == 0)
                {
                    isFound = true;
                    break;
                }
                if (isFound == false)
                {
                    AccountName[numAccount] = in_Account;
                    numAccount++;
                    isAdded = true;
                }
                Email[numAccount] = in_Email;
                Username[numAccount] = in_Username;
                Password[numAccount] = in_Password;
                return isAdded;

            }
        }
```

Comment: Your addAccount function should return a boolean value. Say if numAccount is 0, it will not enter the for loop; hence the error. In a nutshell, you should return a boolean outside for loop as well :-)

Comment: Be careful not to confuse your business knowledge with the knowledge the code has -- for instance, you may know `numAccount` can never be `0`, but the code does not.  For `numAccount <=0` the code will never reach a `return`.  If `numAccount <= 0` is indeed never valid, check for it and throw an exception; but regardless, return a default value at the end of the method. BTW: an alternative to returning within the `for` loop is to `break` out of the loop and have a single `return isAdded` at the end of the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your return inside the `for` structure which depending on conditions, it may not be accessed. You could fix that by doing this:

```
    public bool addAccount(string in_Account, string in_Email, string in_Username, string in_Password)
    {
        bool isFound = false;
        bool isAdded = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < numAccount; i++)
        {
            if (AccountName[i].CompareTo(in_Account) == 0)
            {
                isFound = true;
                break;
            }
            if (isFound == false)
            {
                AccountName[numAccount] = in_Account;
                numAccount++;
                isAdded = true;
            }
            Email[numAccount] = in_Email;
            Username[numAccount] = in_Username;
            Password[numAccount] = in_Password;


        }
        return isAdded;
    }
```

The important thing to realize is (just adding this because you stated you were a beginner at programming) that just because you are sure that such a condition (given your logic) will never happen, the compiler has no way of knowing this. Simply put, the compiler's task here is to enforce that no matter what anomaly in your data turns up, one way or another your method will either return a `bool` value whatever the path of execution is.

Answer (score 0):

`addAccount` needs to return a `bool`, but the problem is that your loop may never execute.  Your looping condition is `for (int i = 0; i < numAccount; i++)`; what happens if `numAccount` starts off as, e.g., `-1`?

What you need to do is return `isAdded` *outside* of the loop.  Just move this line:

```
return isAdded;
```

to below the closing bracket for the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In method

```
public bool addAccount(string in_Account, string in_Email, string in_Username, string in_Password)
{
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < numAccount; i++)
    {
        ...
        return isAdded;
    }
}
```

You returns value inside loop, but you don't return value outside loop, there is error.

Propaby you put } to low in code, and return land in loop.
I think should be:

```
public bool addAccount(string in_Account, string in_Email, string in_Username, string in_Password)
{
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < numAccount; i++)
    {
        ...
    }

    return isAdded;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.The Problem with your part is that you are returning value inside the for loop. The Compiler has no way of knowing it weather you have written a correct logic or not until and unless you run your code. Also, 'return' kind of represents end of the respective block or method, hence you cant return a value for each and every condition of yours. So thats just false, hence compile time error.

```
    public bool addAccount(string in_Account, string in_Email, string in_Username, string in_Password)
    {
        bool isFound = false;
        bool isAdded = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < numAccount; i++)
        {
            if (AccountName[i].CompareTo(in_Account) == 0)
            {
                isFound = true;
                break;
            }
            if (isFound == false)
            {
                AccountName[numAccount] = in_Account;
                numAccount++;
                isAdded = true;
            }
            Email[numAccount] = in_Email;
            Username[numAccount] = in_Username;
            Password[numAccount] = in_Password;                
        }
        return isAdded;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning boolean within the for loop, but if the method does not enters for loop , it will not be able to return any value.this is what happening in your case:

In the constructor, you have declared numaccount = 0

Now, in your method call you are not assigning any value to numaccount, hence it is 0,
So, it will never enter for loop. As

```
    public bool addAccount(string in_Account, string in_Email, string in_Username, string in_Password)
    {
        bool isFound = false;
        bool isAdded = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < numAccount; i++) // here i = numAccount = 0, hence this for loop will never execute
        { 

            /* rest codes*/

              return isAdded;

        }

        /*   No return statement added here, hence the error*/
    }
```